# Replacing pattern using UNIX commands

Tags: unix

I have some strings like:

Sample Input:

```
Also known as temple of the city,
xxx as Pune Banglore as kolkata Delhi India,
as Mumbai India or as Bombay India,
Calcutta,India is now know as Kolkata,India,
```

From the above I want to convert **as xxx xxxx xx,** to **as xxx_xxxx_xx,** and it should be effective after the last **as**.

Sample output for above:

```
Also known as temple_of_the_city,
xxx as Pune Banglore as kolkata_Delhi_India,
as Mumbai India or as Bombay_India,
Calcutta,India is now know as Kolkata,India,
```

There should be no space separated string after the last **as** in a line.

Please let me know if it is not clear.
Thanks

Comment: Where did the second `xxx` in the second line of output come from?

Comment: Sorry Lev, I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul is right that it's not really a simple task. This is a `sed` solution that I put together:

```
sed 's/\(.*as \)/\1\n/;h;y/ /_/;G;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n.*/\2\1/' file.txt
```

Demonstration on your data:

```
$ echo 'Also known as temple of the city,
> xxx as Pune Banglore as kolkata Delhi India,
> as Mumbai India or as Bombay India,
> Calcutta,India is now know as Kolkata,India,' | \
> sed 's/\(.*as \)/\1\n/;h;y/ /_/;G;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n.*/\2\1/'
Also known as temple_of_the_city,
xxx as Pune Banglore as kolkata_Delhi_India,
as Mumbai India or as Bombay_India,
Calcutta,India is now know as Kolkata,India,
```

Comment: @zzk `echo "She has as long as two hours" | sed 's/\(.*as \)/\1\n/;h;y/ /_/;G;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n.*/\2\1/'` does work for me on `GNU sed`.

Comment: perhaps some subtle thing changed when i copy it into my terminal. anyhow.

Comment: @zzk If you're on Mac by any chance, that would explain it. `sed` works differently in OS X.

Comment: Thanks Lev, it is working for me at now.I am familiar to basic sed so, Could please suggest, from where should I get the details about ;h;y and G; options.

Comment: @pkawar First of all, read `man sed` which gives one-line descriptions for those; second of all, I'd recommend [this reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Comment: @LevLevitsky indeed.. i'm using a Mac.. all these default command like 'find', 'grep', 'sed' have this kind of problem..

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to use Perl, the swiss army chainsaw, but sed is also an option. In either case you're looking at a substantial learning curve.

The replacement you've described is probably complex enough that you'd be better off writing a script rather than trying to do it as a one liner.

If you're going to write a script and don't already know Perl there's no reason why you shouldn't pick your scripting language of choice (python, ruby, etc) as long as it has some sort of text pattern matching syntax.

I don't know of a simple, shallow learning curve method of doing a complex pattern match and replacement of this sort. Is this a one time thing where you need to do this replacement only? Or are you going to be doing similar sorts of complicated pattern replacements in the future. If you're going to be doing this frequently you really should invest the time in learning some scripting language but I won't impose my Perl bias on you. Just pick any language that seems accessible.